# Running a Target only once per solution

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, reportgenerator, coverlet

I'm trying to find a way to run a specific target only once per solution after tests are done.

I have a solution with multiple test projects. Each has integration with `coverlet.msbuild`, hence they each produce a coverage report (`opencover`) file in a designated folder.

What I want to achieve is run another target, namely `ReportGenerator`, but only after all the tests are done and all the coverage report files are created. I've successfully created those report after the VSTest target. But that means I generate the report multiple times in a single run, because each testing project is running a `VSTest` target separately.

this is my latest attempt

```xml
<Project>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <CollectCoverage>true</CollectCoverage>
        <CoverletOutput>../../coverage/opencover/$(MSBuildProjectName).xml</CoverletOutput>
        <CoverletOutputFormat>opencover</CoverletOutputFormat>        
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="3.1.0">
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
        <PackageReference Include="coverlet.msbuild" Version="3.1.0">
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
        <PackageReference Include="ReportGenerator" Version="5.0.4" />
    </ItemGroup>
    
    <Target Name="GenerateHtmlCoverageReport" AfterTargets="GenerateCoverageResultAfterTest">
        <ReportGenerator
            ReportFiles="@(CoverletReport)"
            TargetDirectory="../../coverage/html-coverage-report"
            ProjectDirectory="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)"
            ClassFilters="-*OrleansGeneratedCode*"
            HistoryDirectory="../../coverage/history"
            ReportTypes="HTML"
            VerbosityLevel="Verbose" />
    </Target>
    
</Project>
```

**Note**: this is a separate `props` file included in the `Directory.Build.props` that is used by all test projects, just to avoid duplication.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you do to run the tests in the first place? Do you call `dotnet test` on the solution file or on the projects individually?

Comment: @MartinUllrich I'm running `dotnet test` on the solution locally, in the CI we are running `dotnet test` with filter to run the unit & functional together (with coverage) and a separate run for the integration tests (without coverage). this thing gets even more interesting when I'm running multi TFM tests to ensure my multi TFM libraries.
Frankly it looks that I'm better off a `ps1`/`sh` script or a nuke/cake build that trying to make good with `msbuild` in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I've found that it is possible to run specific `targets` only once per solution by customizing the build process as described in the [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-solution-build?view=vs-2022)

the trick was to introduce a `targets` file called `after.<solution name>.sln.targets` near the solution file.

in my case it was:

```xml
<Project>
 <Target Name="GenerateHtmlCoverageReport" AfterTargets="VSTest">
  <Exec Command="ReportGenerator -reports:./tests/coverage/projects/*/*.xml -targetdir:./tests/coverage/report/ -reporttypes:Html_Dark -sourcedirs:./src/ -historydir:./tests/coverage/history" />
 </Target>
</Project>
```

which ran this target after the VSTest target was run, which is only once per solution.